# How to implement i18n(Subdirectories with gTLDs) in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I'm working on a web application that uses Spring Framework, Spring (MVC), Spring Security, etc...
The Spring documentation shows the internationalization adding a parameter in the URL, (e.g. http://myexample.com?lang=fr)
But I have read this article by Google ["Multi-regional and multilingual sites"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192) which states that this practice is not recommended.

So I decided to implement it this way:

http://myexample.com/ -> default locale (EN)

http://myexample.com/es/ -> locale es

http://myexample.com/fr/ -> locale fr

My question is: What is the best way to implement i18n (subdirectories with gTLDs) in Spring framework? Ideas, articles, examples are welcome.

Comment: Implement your own interceptor. The default implementation is using a request parameter, you are free to implement your own. You could also use url rewriting but that feels like overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!-- Defines interceptors for Locale change and Theme change before the request goes to DispatcherServlet for further operation. -->


     <mvc:interceptors>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
        <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
        <!-- <ref bean="conversionServiceExposingInterceptor"/> -->
        </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Interceptor for change in Locale -->
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
<property name="paramName" value="language"/>
</bean>

    <!-- LocaleResolver configuration for internationalization. Here cookie resolver used. Stores and reads the locale value from cookie. -->
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
<property name="defaultLocale" value="1"/>
<property name="cookiePath" value="/WEBPORTAL/" />
<property name="cookieName" value="locale"/>
<property name="cookieMaxAge" value="86400"/>
<property name="cookieHttpOnly" value="true"/>
<property name="cookieSecure" value="true"/>
</bean>

    <!-- Provides the list of base location for Localized property files. Default encoding must be UTF-8 to support multilingual text. -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/labels</value>
        <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/messages</value>
        <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/mailBox</value>
        <value>/project</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

Here is some code which will help you to achieve internationalization 
Just You need to do is add this lines of code into your dispatcher-servlet.xml file and than make changes according to your requirnments

Hope my Reply will guide you ...